# conference live call move that participants to leave voicemail action

Tags: php, plivo

Thing is we have to achieve is.  During conference live call, if participants press certain DTMF like 0, than we have to move that participants to leave voicemail action.

Let me explain you with case, what exactly we want to do is.   We are developing Call Center solution using Plivo voice API.  There is no Call Queue features in Plivo, we are using conference like following steps.

- When a call comes on Plivo number, we will place that call in conference with hold music until we get free agent to connect with.  Here some time caller have to wait longer time to connect with agent.  We want to give features like “Press 0 to arrange call back or Press 9 to leave your name and number in voicemail and get back to you”.
- During stay on hold in conference, caller will press either 0 or 9 digit to generate appropriate action, either we play call back request in database or move that caller to leave voicemail and hangup the call.

Can you guide us how we can use this using Plivo Conference feature or do you have any kind of method where we can manage call queue functionality.

As you know in call center if there is less agents to answer incoming call and high incoming call volume,  call will be stay in queue for certain period with this features.  Caller can take decision either they stay and wait in queue to connect with agent or leave with selection option.

Please let me know how we can achieve this features using Plivo API.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my self.

first create conference

incomingcalltest.php

```
 <Response>
<Conference waitSound="<?php echo $url; ?>waitmusic.php" callbackUrl="<?php echo $url; ?>testcallbackurl.php"  digitsMatch="0,9">testroom</Conference>

</Response>
```

than create waitmusic.php for wait music

```
 <Response>

    <Play><?php echo $url; ?>MyMusicTherapy.mp3</Play>
    <Speak>Please press 0 to disconnect the call or press 1 to leave a voicemail </Speak>

 </Response>
```

than create callback url page and write code

```
$ConferenceDigitsMatch = $_REQUEST['ConferenceDigitsMatch'];

  if($ConferenceDigitsMatch == '0'){

$p = new RestAPI($auth_id, $auth_token);

$string = 'testroom';
$params = array(
    'conference_name' => $string, # ID of the call
);
$resp = $p->get_live_conference($params);
foreach ($resp['response']['members'] as $num) {
    $call_uuid = $num['call_uuid'];
    $parameters = array(
        'call_uuid' => $call_uuid,
        'aleg_url' => <?php echo $url; ?>.'test.php', # URL to transfer for aleg
    );
    $transfer_call = $p->transfer_call($parameters);

   }

    }
```

and create new file for transfer call for voice mail and past code

```
  <Response>
    <Speak>Please leave a message after the beep. Press the star key when done. </Speak>
    <Record action="<?php echo $url; ?>plivo_call_record.php" maxLength="30" finishOnKey="*" />
    <Speak>Recording not received.</Speak>
</Response>
```